# JQuery SlideToggle Effect: Slide One List Only & Unworking Links

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, expand

I came across two issues with a list menu that I've been working with for awhile now.

1. I cant get the list to expand one list only (one or two, not one and two).
2. ~FIXED~I have absolutely no idea why the links wont work.~FIXED~

Here is the JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/yAqQG/1/

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

**HTML**

```
<div class="navigation">
<ul>
<li><h1><a href="#">One</a></h1>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Not Available</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Not Available</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><h1><a href="#">Two</a></h1>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Not Available</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Not Available</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    var subMenu = jQuery(".navigation ul li ul li");
    var linkClick = jQuery(".navigation ul li").filter(":has(ul)");

    subMenu.hide();

    linkClick.click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).find('ul li').slideToggle("fast");
    });
});
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    background : #000000;
}

/* Title Settings */
.navigation ul li h1 {
    background : none;
    float : right;
    font-size : 28px;
    font-weight : 100;
    margin : 0;
    margin-bottom : 3px;
    padding : 0;
}
/* Before and After Styling */
.navigation a {
    color : #ffffff;
    border-right : 3px solid #ffffff;
    display : table;
    padding : 6px;
    transition: .25s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
    text-decoration : none;
}
.navigation a:hover {
    border-right : 3px solid #f43058;
    color : #f43058;
}
/* Fixed (Top Right) Positioning */
.navigation {
    font-family : 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
    font-weight : 100;
    margin : 12px;
    position : fixed;
    right : 0;
    top : 0;
}
.navigation ul {
    font-size : 20px;
    margin : 0;
    padding : 0;
    text-align : right;
}
.navigation ul li {
    clear : right;
    float : right;
    list-style-type : none;
}
/* Second Level Settings */
.navigation ul li:hover ul {
    display : block;
}
.navigation ul li ul li {
    font-size : 18px;
    margin-bottom : 3px;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your links don't work because you've applied preventDefault to all of them:

```
linkClick.click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

I've removed the `a` tag from around your h1 tags instead. To get accordion working, you could do this:

http://jsfiddle.net/W8H6W/3/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('h1').click(function () {
        $(this).closest('li').siblings().find('ul').slideUp();
        $(this).siblings('ul').slideToggle("fast");
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm trying it out on my template, so far the slide function is working perfectly but the link wasn't working in the jsfiddle, hoping it'll work on my page.

Comment: The Google links don't work, but that's not due to my code. Change the links to something else and they work: http://jsfiddle.net/W8H6W/6/

Comment: The slide function however isn't working when adding it to my template, seemed fine in jsfiddle, but here is what happens with my css - http://jsfiddle.net/yAqQG/2/

Comment: You have a bunch of hover styles that are blowing up the slider. You need to drastically simplify.

Comment: Put an explicit height on your second-level LIs to prevent slide jump: http://jsfiddle.net/yAqQG/4/

Comment: Here's your CSS simplified and organized hierarchically: http://jsfiddle.net/yAqQG/6/